# How to test a method in controller and service layer to insert a register with Junit Mocks?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, junit, mockito

I have the following methods in a service layer an a repository to insert a new register in BD, I want to do the Unit test with Mocks but I dont know how

controller

```
    @PostMapping("/altaDiaInhabil")
    private void addWorkingDay(@RequestBody CatDiaEntity day) throws Exception {
        try {
            catDiaInhabilService.addNewWorkingDay(day);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error in CatDiaEntity Values ");
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

serviceImpl

```
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void addNewWorkingDay(CatDiaEntity dayOff) throws Exception {
        try {
            catDiaRepository.saveWorkingDay(dayOff.getFechaInb(), dayOff.getDescDiaInb(),
                    dayOff.getInhaMx(), dayOff.getInhabCh());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("An error ocurred to insert CatDiaEntity Data");

        }

    }
```

I try to do the testcase like this for the service, but show the error message

> The method when in the type Mockito is not applicable for the
> arguments void

```
      @Mock
    private CatDiaRepository catDiaRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private CatDiaServiceImpl serviceImpl;
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        catDiEnatity = new CatDiaEntity();

    }
        @Test
        public void testAddNewRecord() {
            catDiEnatity.setFechaInb("12/12/24");
            catDiEnatity.setDescDiaInb("New day");
            catDiEnatity.setInhaMx("1");
            catDiEnatity.setInhabCh("0");
            
            Mockito.when(catDiaRepository.saveWorkingDay(catDiEnatity.getFechaInb(), catDiEnatity.getDescDiaInb(), 
                    catDiEnatity.getInhaMx(), catDiEnatity.getInhabCh())).thenReturn();
        }
```

How can I test these two methods?

Comment: what  is returning of `saveWorkingDay` ? is  CatDia entity class ?

Comment: Its a void method, this method is the query to insert

Comment: usually a `save method` should return something, but if you dont want this you can just test invoke of this method in service with `verify() from mockito because it return nothing

Comment: i just added a correct way to test  what you want

Answer (score 1):

In your case if repository return type is `void` you should test invoke of service with method your current test case will look so:

```
@Test
public void testAddNewRecord() {
    catDiEnatity.setFechaInb("12/12/24");
    catDiEnatity.setDescDiaInb("New day");
    catDiEnatity.setInhaMx("1");
    catDiEnatity.setInhabCh("0");

    serviceImpl.addNewWorkingDay(catDiEnatity);

    verify(catDiaRepository, times(1)).saveWorkingDay(catDiEnatity.getFechaInb(), catDiEnatity.getDescDiaInb(), 
                catDiEnatity.getInhaMx(), catDiEnatity.getInhabCh());
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works!!,  this also apply to the controller test?

Comment: yes of course but for controller test you will mock service layer and test invoke of method also with verify, because it`s the same as repository with void return

Comment: yes, I already implemented it like this and it also works, Thank you  lot.                         how can I validate when it falls into the exception?

Comment: I don't know how to cover that scenario

Comment: you can mock(simulate) a throwing of exception when call it with mockito library